geoserver: Connection to external wms fails
When I set up a connection to an external wms service in my geoserver, the connection test fails with the error "connection reset".
I already switched http-connection-pooling on and of, with no success. When I enter the url of the capabilities document in my browser, the information is shown as expected.
In the log-file, the following message occurs: "ERROR  [data.ows] - Failed to execute request".
Here the content of the extended log:
28 Mai 16:24:47 CONFIG [geoserver.logging] - Log4j 2 configuration set to GEOTOOLS_DEVELOPER_LOGGING.xml
28 Mai 16:24:47 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 "POST /geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.GlobalSettingsPage?25-1.IFormSubmitListener-form&filter=false" took 96ms
28 Mai 16:24:47 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 "GET /geoserver/web/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/125.0.0.0" "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.GlobalSettingsPage?25&filter=false" "" 
28 Mai 16:24:47 WARN   [geoserver.security] - Failed login, user admin from 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
28 Mai 16:24:47 INFO   [geoserver.security] - Brute force attack prevention, delaying login for 4870ms
28 Mai 16:24:52 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 "GET /geoserver/web/" took 4985ms
28 Mai 16:24:52 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 "GET /geoserver/web/?27" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/125.0.0.0" "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.GlobalSettingsPage?25&filter=false" "" 
28 Mai 16:24:52 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 "GET /geoserver/web/?27" took 30ms
28 Mai 16:24:55 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 "GET /geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.data.store.StorePage?filter=false" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/125.0.0.0" "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web/?27" "" 
28 Mai 16:24:55 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 "GET /geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.data.store.StorePage?filter=false" took 115ms
28 Mai 16:24:55 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 "GET /geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.data.store.StorePage?30&filter=false" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/125.0.0.0" "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web/?27" "" 
28 Mai 16:24:55 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 "GET /geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.data.store.StorePage?30&filter=false" took 46ms
28 Mai 16:24:58 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 "GET /geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.data.store.NewDataPage" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/125.0.0.0" "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.data.store.StorePage?30&filter=false" "" 
28 Mai 16:24:58 TRACE  [geotools.util] - Loaded resources for <default> from bundle "org.geotools.metadata.i18n".
28 Mai 16:24:58 DEBUG  [gce.arcgrid] - ArcGridFormatFactory is available.
28 Mai 16:24:58 DEBUG  [gdal.mrsid] - MrSIDFormatFactory is not available.
28 Mai 16:24:58 DEBUG  [gdal.jp2kak] - JP2KFormatFactory is not available.
28 Mai 16:24:58 DEBUG  [gdal.jp2mrsid] - JP2MrSIDFormatFactory is not available.
28 Mai 16:24:58 DEBUG  [gdal.jp2ecw] - JP2ECWFormatFactory is available.
28 Mai 16:24:58 DEBUG  [gdal.ecw] - ECWFormatFactory is available.
28 Mai 16:24:58 DEBUG  [gdal.dted] - DTEDFormatFactory is available.
28 Mai 16:24:58 DEBUG  [gdal.erdasimg] - ErdasImgFormatFactory is available.
28 Mai 16:24:58 DEBUG  [gdal.idrisi] - IDRISIFormatFactory is available.
28 Mai 16:24:58 DEBUG  [gdal.nitf] - NITFFormatFactory is available.
28 Mai 16:24:58 DEBUG  [gdal.ehdr] - EsriHdrFormatFactory is available.
28 Mai 16:24:58 DEBUG  [gdal.envihdr] - EnviHdrFormatFactory is available.
28 Mai 16:24:58 DEBUG  [gdal.aig] - AIGFormatFactory is available.
28 Mai 16:24:58 DEBUG  [gdal.rpftoc] - RPFTOCFormatFactory is available.
28 Mai 16:24:58 DEBUG  [gdal.vrt] - VRTFormatFactory is available.
28 Mai 16:24:58 DEBUG  [gdal.srp] - SRPFormatFactory is available.
28 Mai 16:24:58 DEBUG  [gdal.nitf] - Creating a new NITFFormat.
28 Mai 16:24:58 DEBUG  [gdal.jp2ecw] - Creating a new JP2KFormat.
28 Mai 16:24:58 DEBUG  [gdal.ecw] - Creating a new ECWFormat.
28 Mai 16:24:58 DEBUG  [gce.arcgrid] - Creating a new ArcGriFormat.
28 Mai 16:24:58 DEBUG  [gdal.srp] - Creating a new SRPFormat.
28 Mai 16:24:58 DEBUG  [gdal.erdasimg] - Creating a new ErdasImgFormat.
28 Mai 16:24:58 DEBUG  [gdal.idrisi] - Creating a new IDRISIFormat.
28 Mai 16:24:58 DEBUG  [gdal.ehdr] - Creating a new EsriHdrFormat.
28 Mai 16:24:58 DEBUG  [gdal.aig] - Creating a new AIGFormat.
28 Mai 16:24:58 DEBUG  [gdal.rpftoc] - Creating a new RPFTOCFormat.
28 Mai 16:24:58 DEBUG  [gdal.vrt] - Creating a new VRTFormat.
28 Mai 16:24:58 DEBUG  [gdal.envihdr] - Creating a new EnviHdrFormat.
28 Mai 16:24:58 DEBUG  [gdal.dted] - Creating a new DTEDFormat.
28 Mai 16:24:58 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 "GET /geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.data.store.NewDataPage" took 59ms
28 Mai 16:24:58 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 "GET /geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.data.store.NewDataPage?31" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/125.0.0.0" "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.data.store.StorePage?30&filter=false" "" 
28 Mai 16:24:58 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 "GET /geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.data.store.NewDataPage?31" took 66ms
28 Mai 16:25:01 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 "POST /geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.data.store.NewDataPage?31-1.IFormSubmitListener-storeForm" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/125.0.0.0" "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.data.store.NewDataPage?31" "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
28 Mai 16:25:01 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 "POST /geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.data.store.NewDataPage?31-1.IFormSubmitListener-storeForm" took 3ms
28 Mai 16:25:01 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 "GET /geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.data.store.WMSStoreNewPage" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/125.0.0.0" "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.data.store.NewDataPage?31" "" 
28 Mai 16:25:01 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 "GET /geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.data.store.WMSStoreNewPage" took 24ms
28 Mai 16:25:01 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 "GET /geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.data.store.WMSStoreNewPage?32" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/125.0.0.0" "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.data.store.NewDataPage?31" "" 
28 Mai 16:25:01 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 "GET /geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.data.store.WMSStoreNewPage?32" took 24ms
28 Mai 16:25:13 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 "POST /geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.data.store.WMSStoreNewPage?32-1.IBehaviorListener.0-form-save" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/125.0.0.0" "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.data.store.WMSStoreNewPage?32" "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" 
28 Mai 16:25:13 DEBUG  [data.ows] - FinalURL:https://sgx.geodatenzentrum.de/wms_basemapde?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.3.0&SERVICE=WMS
28 Mai 16:25:13 DEBUG  [geotools.http] - URL is https://sgx.geodatenzentrum.de/wms_basemapde?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.3.0&SERVICE=WMS
28 Mai 16:25:13 DEBUG  [geotools.http] - Setting header User-Agent = GeoTools HTTPClient (30.2)
28 Mai 16:25:13 ERROR  [data.ows] - Failed to execute request https://sgx.geodatenzentrum.de/wms_basemapde?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.3.0&SERVICE=WMS
28 Mai 16:25:13 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 "POST /geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.data.store.WMSStoreNewPage?32-1.IBehaviorListener.0-form-save" took 165ms
28 Mai 16:25:15 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 "GET /geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.LogPage?filter=false" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/125.0.0.0" "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.data.store.WMSStoreNewPage?32" "" 



Turn logging up to GeoTools developer level and try again. Then add the full log file entry

Thanks for the hint. I added the extended log in my first post ...

Not sure what's up as it works fine on my machine - do you have a web proxy?

Maybe the problem are the settings of the hosting server. It is situated in a special area of the network for security reasons ...

Does geoserver use a specific tcp/ip-port to communicate with external wms-sources? If yes, which ones? Maybe, I can open these ports in the firewall. My wms, hosted on geoserver are accessible normally from outside.
